# Passing parameters through django url error

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have been trying to load my localhost:8000/streamers/1234 however there is a bug in my urls that I cannot seem to fix. Iv tried both patterns below and I keep getting the error:

Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^streamers/(?P[0-9]+)/$ [name='streamer']
The current path, streamers/34/, didn't match any of these.

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path(r'^streamers/<int:id>/', views.streamer, name='streamer'),
    url(r'^streamers/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.streamer, name='streamer'),
]
```

Comment: Your regex seems fine. What is your error? Any traceback there ?

Comment: from `django 2.0`, it is better to use `re_path()` instead of `url()`

Answer (score 0):

if "views.streamer" is a class based view, use:

```
path(r'^streamers/<int:id>/', views.streamer.as_view(), name='streamer'),
```

Notice the "as_view()" after views.streamer.

Comment: I don't think so, Because if he'd used an FBV, then it's not required/mandatory